# OSError: [Errno 8] when running selenium in python in a docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, windows-10, chromium, python-3.6

I've recently learned the basics of Docker and how to create and run images. I'm trying to create an image of a python script that scrapes some webpages for data and uploads it to a server. I'm using Selenium, Chromium, and a Windows chromedriver. I'm trying to build the image on my Windows machine and be able to deploy it on a bunch of Linux/Windows servers. Currently, I'm only building and running on the same Windows machine, just until I get it running, but I keep getting the same error, even though the script runs just fine directly on the machine itself.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-app.py", line 796, in <module>
    startScraper();
  File "my-app.py", line 92, in startScraper
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path = path_to_chromedriver);
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

It seems to be related to the chrome options but even when I remove all the "add-argument" options, the error persists, but here are the options:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.binary_location = './chrome-win32/chrome.exe';
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1400x1300')
options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security');
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content');
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs);
path_to_chromedriver = './chromedriver.exe';
```

Is there anything that I'm missing to be able to run this scraper in a container? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to add the Dockerfile and how I build/run the image:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.0

WORKDIR /my-app

ADD . /my-app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV NAME Scraper

CMD ["python", "My_App.py"]
```

Build/Run image:
- docker build -t myapp
- docker run myapp

Maybe there are some options that I don't know about that I'm missing?

Comment: Try `RUN chmod 0444 /my-app/My_App.py` before the `CMD` line

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a exe inside a linux container and that is not going to work. You will need to install chrome and chromedriver inside your Dockerfile and update the code to use the correct path

```
FROM python:3.6.0
RUN apt update && apt install -y chromedriver
WORKDIR /my-app
ADD . /my-app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV NAME Scraper

CMD ["python", "My_App.py"]
```

Change your code to

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1400x1300')
options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security');
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content');
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs);
path_to_chromedriver = '/usr/lib/chromium/chromedriver';
```